# Basic UDP networking doesn't receive

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking, udp, portforwarding

I'm trying to learn UDP networking so I tried the simplest code to begin with. It's a python code client-server that works perfectly when I send data to localhost or to the LAN IP from the same computer, but it doesn't work when I try to send from my computer using the public IP, and also doesn't work from another computer using private network IP or public IP.

I did the port forwarding, created the input rules for windows firewall, turned off the router internal firewall, and it still doesn't work.

When I scan my port from canyouseeme.org or using netcat it says connection refused and port closed.

Maybe somebody can guess what is happening here or what may I do to succeed?
I write the code below in case it's needed.

Server:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_PORT = XXXX

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    message = data.decode()
    print("received message:", message)
```

Client:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.133"
UDP_PORT = XXXX
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

print("UDP target IP:", UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port:", UDP_PORT)
print("message:", MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE.encode(), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I have found a partial solution. I'm posting an answer because it may help some people with similar problems, but it's not the best solution yet, so the issue is still there.

I found that there's no problem in communicating within a LAN if I **completely disable the firewall** in both computers. I don't know why the input rules or exceptions don't work.

For networking beyond the LAN I have tried successfully to use a virtual LAN (i.e. hamachi) and there's no necessity of port forwarding nor disabling the firewall. The bad thing about hamachi is that I don't control the protocol it uses, and I don't control the way of ensuring reliability.

For the applications I'm dealing with right now I probably have enough with this solution, but it would be interesting to know more.